# Why is this exported typescript const not available for being imported from transpiled and bundled code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack-4, transpiler

I have some typescript code like so:

```
// file.ts
export const MyValues: {
  [key: string]: string;
} = {
  value: 'This is a value'
};
```

Which is then transpiled by tsc (module: ES2015) to:

```
// file.js
export var MyValues = {
    value: 'This is a value'
};
```

along with typings like so:

```
// file..d.ts
export declare const MyValues: {
    [key: string]: string;
};
```

...which seem correct to me.

The js file is then bundled with webpack. It results in:

```
// <webpack boostrap stuff>

var MyValues= {
    value: 'This is a value'
};
```

But when I use this built library, and try to import this exported const, the IDE can't auto-import (even though the typings are there and if I Ctrl + click on this constant, it finds it), and if I import manually like so:

`import {MyValues} from 'mylibrary';`

It comes as null, not as the object value being assigned on that var declaration.

**Why is this happening and how to fix it?**

**UPDATE: ** I noticed at the bottom of the webpack bundled code, I see:

```
__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "MyValues", function() { return MyValues; });
```

But still, can't access a value for it. It remains undefined if I import it manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to import from the bundled file that has no `export` declaration?

Comment: @Bergi please see my update, found an export that ends up transforming that const into a function I need to call to get the value. I would like the const to be available directly, without being transformed into a function. That's pretty odd.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that line installs a `.MyValues` getter on the `__webpack_exports__` object. My recommendation is to simply import from the original source file, not from transpiled script.

Comment: Right, but I am writing a library. I am in the process of using the library as it is to be packed and distributed.

Comment: Then distribute in ES6 format as well. Or use something like UMD, and tell your library user to configure *his* bundler to refer to that distributable correctly.

Comment: Ah, your clue lead me to the solution. I needed to add `library: 'mylibrary', libraryTarget: 'umd'` to the webpack config. Would you please add it as an answer so I can mark as resolved?

Comment: You can [post the answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I'm not really familiar with webpack.